# Use a div as a mask over a fixed image

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I'd like to had a specific design to a webpage i'm designing.

The main wrapper contains a succession of `<div class='section'>` and `<div class='section-header'>`. The `section-header` should display the section's title over an image.

exemple:

```
<div id="tag" class="section-header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img src="assets/img/some_image.jpg">
</div>
```

So far my css is:

```
.section-header
{
    width:            100%;
    height:           192px;
    overflow:         hidden;
}
.section-header > *
{
    width:            100%;
    line-height:      192px;
    margin:           0;
}
.section-header > h1
{
    position:         absolute;
    z-index:          10000;
    text-align:       center;
}
.section-header > img
{
    filter:           opacity(50%);
}
```

however i'd like to add some relative movement between the background image and the `section-header`. I basically wanted to fixe the image to the screen with `position: fixed;` and let the `overflow: none;` do the job.

However it appears that as soon as I add `position: fixed; top: 0;` to `.section-header > img`, the overflow isn't hidden anymore and the image is visible regardless of the position of the header it's nested in.

How can I solve that ?

Edit:
devel code is visible [here](https://dev.hadriencroubois.com/). I'd basically have the image behind each section's title not to scrool with the page, and just to have the section's header reveal it as you scrool

Comment: can't you use the img as background ? can you clariyf what *some relative movement* means ... also a the expected output as an img maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the effect you want, you may need to use the `img` as background; try this:

```css
body{
  background: #f3f3f3;
  height:800px;
}
div {
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  width:80%;
  margin:150px auto;
  line-height:200px;
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600') no-repeat center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div h1 {
  font-size:3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Mytitle</h1>
</div>
```

---

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5j4vor44/)

Comment: Thats à very nice solution, except it is not very effective for changing the image for each header at the HTML level. I found à solution using clip : rect in a dedicated div (see link)

Comment: well you can easily change just the bg-image for each container with nth-child or setting classnames @Amxx and i think it's better supported thatn use clip

Answer (score 0):

Overflow is ignored for `position:absolute` children in parent that is relatively positioned.

One way of fixing the problem is giving `.section-header` a `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` too. (whichever is most useful for you).

like this :

```
.section-header
{
    width:            100%;
    height:           192px;
    overflow:         hidden;
    position:         absolute;
}
```

[see this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eao0vkrd/)